# Python get script output with now only the pid of file

Tags: python, stdout, pid

for example I run a script

```
os.execv('script.py',('',))
```

As I read in docs this command starts a script from your current script by taking it's pid and reasigning it to run script.py. So I can get the pid of process.
The question is following:
After running execv I need to get the stdout of this script, and the only thing I know is the pid of process. Is it possible to perform this with python ? Any suggestions ? I need to use only `execv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution redirecting the output to a file.

```
import os,sys
sys.stdout = open("./data.out","w")
os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), 1)
os.execv('/usr/bin/python', ['python', './script.py'])
```

Comment: Great, thats what I was talking about. Thanks

Comment: But can you please also help to do this unbuffering ? so that execv script output doesn't collect a buffer , but immidiately puts the data in file ?

Comment: @user3581394 yes the output is a file

Comment: Hmm I'm talking about non blocking output to a file, like:
print 'hi' runs in a file
 'hi' is written to to /data.outprint, 
 'goodbye' runs in a file
 'goodbye' is written to to /data.out.
 So that it happens in real time

Answer (score 0):

`os.execv` is just binding to execve system call. Thing that you need is a `subprocess` module:

```
import sys
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'script.py'],
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
print(proc.stdout.read())
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: But subprocess creates a child process that may result in zombie process. So I can't use the subprocess module

Comment: proc.wait() will ensure you do not get zombies. You may add it to finally block. os.execv() completely replaces you image that means that after calling it your current script is dead, only script "script.py" exists